# Get Only One Record For Every Date

Tags: sql, syntax, count

I have a question,

I have table like this:

```
|------|------------|---------|
| [Id] |   [Date]   | [InOut] |
|------|------------|---------|
|  10  | 2018-05-01 |    IN   |
|  10  | 2018-05-01 |    IN   |
|  10  | 2018-05-02 |    IN   |
|  10  | 2018-05-03 |    IN   |
|------|------------|---------|
```

What I want is to count [InOut] 1 record per date which means returns 3 not 4

I already use this query: `SELECT DISTINCT COUNT([Date]), [Id] FROM AttLog GROUP BY [Date], [Id]`

but its not work, i just get 1

please help me with the correct query, thank you in advance

Comment: Astonishing you get a result, without table name.

Comment: thank you for your correction, I edited the question

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name mark the square brackets ;-)  Not that it matters.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [Date], [Id], count([InOut]) from AttLog GROUP BY [Date], [Id]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer,i change the question, because the InOut is varchar, not int, so it cannot be summed, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you want:

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(DISTINCT [Date])
FROM AttLog
GROUP BY [Id];
```

I can't figure out if `InOut` is a filter condition or aggregation condition, but you might want to add it to the `GROUP BY` and `SELECT`:

```
SELECT ID, INOUT, COUNT(DISTINCT [Date])
FROM AttLog
GROUP BY Id, INOUT;
```